# SSRS Expression error handling

Tags: reporting-services

I am using the following expression in one of my report fields.

=Fields!Value.Value*(Fields!DutyRate.Value/100)

This works as exprected as long as there is a valid value in the Fields!DutyRate.Value.

My problem is that the Fields!DutyRate.Value can contain non numerical values such as "Free".

This means any rows with the word "Free" in them causes an #Error. This is OK as such but I would like to get SSRS to display something other than #Error. In fact I would like to to display "F" instead.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an IIF (inline if statement) and the IsNumeric function.

```
Syntax: IIF(<condition>,<true part>,<false part>)

=IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!DutyRate.Value),Fields!Value.Value*(Fields!DutyRate.Value/100),"F")
```

[SSRS Expression Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx)

[Visual Basic Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32s6akha.aspx) (SSRS expressions use VB functions)

Comment: I am afraid that did not work. I manged to get around it in the end by writting a CASE expression; CASE WHEN CustomsTariff.CommodityCode.StandardDuty = 'Free' THEN '0.0' ELSE SUBSTRING(CustomsTariff.CommodityCode.StandardDuty, 1, 3) 
                         END AS DutyRate1. Bit long winded but it seems to work. Thanks anyway.